# Flutter - Handle device orientation: layout rotate but next returns automatically to portrait

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have a simple page in **Flutter** and I need to manage the orientation, changing the layout if portrait or landscape.

What I've done:
In my widget I added the allowed orientations for this page:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight
    ]);

    var screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final isLandscape = screenSize.width > screenSize.height;

    [...]
```

Now in my code I was able to manage the layout with success, using for instance something like this:

```
Flex(children: [
  isLandscape ? Spacer() : Container(),
[...]
```

or the `Row()` / `Column()` switching if needed.

**What happens is that**: when I rotate the device from portrait to landscape, the layout change with animation, but returns back to portrait also if the device is rotated once transition is completed.

---

**STEP 1 -> PORTRAIT**:
[image]

---

**STEP 2 -> ROTATING FROM PORTRAIT TO LANDSCAPE**
[image]

---

**STEP 3 -> ISSUE AFTER LANDSCAPE COMPLETED**
[image]

---

I have no idea on why this happens. If instead I force the orientation to portrait or landscape only, everything works well:

```
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight
    ]);
```

as you can see from the picture below:
[image]

This is the behavior on iOS, these are the iOS settings:

[image]

On Android instead, not rotate.

Why this happen? What I can do to avoid this?

---

**EDIT 1**:

After @*PeterKoltai* suggestion, I've used `OrientationBuilder`; is ok, rotate with success on device rotation.
The issue described here happens only if in the previous page the `setPreferredOrientations` is forced to portrait.
If I use the 4 orientations for each page, no issue at all, but all pages rotates...
Of course, I need to allow rotation for some pages, other must be only portraits.

Comment: Have you considered using an [OrientationBuilder](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/orientation)?

Comment: Ok @PeterKoltai, using `OrientationBuilder` and lot of works behind, is ok, rotate with success on device rotation. The issue described in the question happens only if in the previous page the `setPreferredOrientations` is forced to `portrait`. If I use all orientation for each page, no issue at all. Of course, as the scope of the question, I need to allow rotation for some pages, other must be only portraits...